# Rspec is different from the app

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I'm currently working on a Ruby/Sinatra App and now I'm stuck because my rspec testing is not working properly on the controller. But when I tried my API using curl or web the code just works!.

Here are my file, spesificly on that line of code

listproduct_controller.rb

```
get '/' do
    products = Product.all
    payload = []
    products.each do |product|
        payload.push({ :exhibit_name => product.exhibit_name, :icon => product.icon })
    end

    return {
        :status => 'SUCCESS',
        :message => 200,
        :payload => payload
    }.to_json
end
```

and here are my spec file
listproduct_controller_spec.rb

```
context "GET to /products" do
  before { allow(Product).to receive(:all) }
  before { allow(Product).to receive(:find_by) }

  it "returns status 200 OK" do
    get '/'
    puts(last_response)
    expect(last_response).to be_ok
  end

  it "show a list of product's name and its icon" do
    get '/'
    @products = Product.all.to_a
    expect(last_response.body).to include_json(@products)
  end
end
```

When I puts the last_response on spec it shows this

```
500 
{"Content-Type"=>"text/html", "Content-Length"=>"212150"}
#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x0000000480b1d8>
```

but when im using curl or apps it just works and return
200 status code with the payload

Can anyone help me what I did wrong?

UPDATE :

I solved it, it was the problem on the database, where all the product in the development database were not on the test database so it returns 500 of empty database.

Comment: Is this your complete `listproduct_controller_spec.rb`? Are you including `Rack::Test::Methods` anywhere?

Comment: I include that in my spec_helper.rb

Comment: anything interesting in the logs?

Comment: The logs from the rspec get output like this
 Failure/Error: expect(last_response).to be_ok
       expected `#<Rack::MockResponse:0x000000037d42d8 @original_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html", "Content-Length...bled the <code>show_exceptions</code> setting.</p>\n  </div> <!-- /WRAP -->\n  </body>\n</html>\n"]>.ok?` to return true, got false

in the rspec failure, i think it because it returns 500